# Parse : Unknown type name NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am trying to build one of the parse library (https://github.com/layerhq/Layer-Parse-iOS-Example). I had install the pod file but it gives me error when I am trying try to build.

Attached a screen shot.

[image]

I have no idea what the error say. anyone?

Comment: Show the full error text from the compiler so we can see what file(s) is causing the issue.

Comment: thanks for the responce. attached a screen shot

Comment: It's kinda localized; I would raise an issue on the github repo.

Comment: Sorry i didn't get. its kinda localized means?

Comment: From the look of it your version of Xcode is too old for this framework. Which version are you using ? And what's your operation system ?

Comment: Ohhh I m using xcode 6.2 with yosemite os

Comment: @SidShah You need at least Xcode 6.3 or greater for this code to compile, with regards to nullability. See more here: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=25

Comment: I have the same issue in Xcode 9.2